# scipy least_squares function not found

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I've been following this guide http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#example-of-solving-a-fitting-problem to do a least squares fit on my data, but I am unable to import the function least_squares.  I am using windows, and have anaconda https://www.continuum.io/downloads.  I get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'least_squares' when trying to import the function by using the line "from scipy.optimize import least_squares". I would appreciate some help with this.  Thank you.

Comment: `least_squares` was added in version 0.17.0 of scipy.  What version do you have?  You can check by running `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem!